# Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin : Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I try to install the  `SVN Publisher` for connecting Jenkins to Subversion Repository.

As I install through `Download Now and Install after Restart`, My Jenkins is taking so long time to [restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344061/please-wait-while-jenkins-is-restarting-waiting-long) so I tried with `Install without restart`.

It shows the following error

```
 Failure -

java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1308)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1107)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to expand C:\tomcat\webapps\.jenkins\plugins\svnpublisher.jpi
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:460)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:126)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:415)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1304)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: Error while expanding C:\tomcat\webapps\.jenkins\plugins\svnpublisher.jpi
java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.unzipExceptClasses(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:532)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:457)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:481)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:320)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:170)
    ... 11 more
```

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that there has been an issue during download so that plugin file got corrupted. Shutdown Jenkins, delete `C:\tomcat\webapps\.jenkins\plugins\svnpublisher.jpi`, restart jenkins and reattempt plugin installation.

Alternatively download file manually and replace with one on file system, it should be available from here `https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/`

Comment: Can you help me how to move my .jenkins folder from
 C:\tomcat\webapps\.jenkins to C:\.jenkins\

Comment: I'm not using Windows version not installed Jenkins on tomcat. So in general renaming should work: shutdown app server, rename app folder, start up tomcat. For jenkins on win I don't know if there is a configuration file somewhere else that defines JENKINS_HOME or if renaming would have impact on running jenkins as windows service, maybe start https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+Windows+Installer and see what impacts there may be.