# Error at install the Selenium Grid on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid

I'm triying to install the selenium grid plugin but when I make this...this error appear, so please help me, or if there is a plugin to run multiple selenium's test suite at time I want to know. Thanks:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1322)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1121)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\Nicolás\.jenkins\plugins\selenium\WEB-INF\lib\classes.jar: El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso.

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:247)
at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:310)
at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:212)
at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:301)
at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:212)
at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:301)
at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:212)
at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:301)
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:522)
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:166)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:448)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1318)
... 5 more
```

The long file in spanish says " The process can't access to the file because is used by other process"

Comment: probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821756/failed-to-dynamically-deploy-this-plugin-jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer searching on Google and I had to put the .jenkins folder in the root of the hard drive:

When I run the jenkins.war it unzip a folder in the user's folder. But I moved this folder to C:/ creating an environment variable.